# My innodb table returns 0 for count(*)

Tags: mysql, count, innodb

I'm doing this query at the mysql command line (not through any kind of code)

```
select count(*) from books where
publisher_id = 46 AND deleted = 0 AND status_id = 3;
```

Returns 0 (sometimes), but remove the count, it has many results.

What could be causing this? I'm throwing this query at the command line (not through any kind of programming layer)

Explaining count query gives:

```
Using intersect(IDX_cms_books_publisher_id,IDX_cms_books_status_id,IDX_cms_books_deleted); Using where; Using index
```

Comment: `Returns 0 (sometimes), but remove the count, it has many results.` What `sometimes` means?

Comment: 444,282205220........ (it's too large, here's the query in case you're skeptical)

select * from books where
  publisher_id = 46 AND deleted = 0 AND status_id = 3 LIMIT 1

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/14/the-optimization-that-often-isnt-index-merge-intersection/+

Comment: Yes, but it's one thing to be slow, and another to give a wrong result! @DanFromGermany

Comment: I just encountered this bug. It seems to have only started happening after the table involved reached some size threshold.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be a bug with mysql. It's caused by index merge intersection.

You can either set it per session
SET SESSION optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off";

Or set it globally in your my.cnf

[mysqld]
optimizer_switch=index_merge_intersection=off

Bug report filed here

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81031

Answer (score 0):

You can both avoid the bug and make the query faster by adding a 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(publisher_id, deleted, status_id)
```

(The columns may be in any order.)

If `PARTITION BY HASH` is involved, perhaps [bug 70588](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70588) is involved.  It was fixed in 5.5.36, 5.6.16, 5.7.4.